# Codeigniter Zoho Mail Sending Mails

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, zoho

I'd like to send to a user when they register for an account. I am using zoho mail. I have gone through several articles on this, but still I cant seem to crack this.

```
    $email=$this->session->userdata('email');
    $ci = get_instance();
    $ci->load->library('email');
    $config['useragent'] = "CodeIgniter";
    $config['protocol'] = "smtp";
    $config['_smtp_auth']   = TRUE;
    $config['smtp_host'] = "ssl://smtp.zoho.com";
    $config['smtp_user'] = "my_email";
    $config['smtp_pass'] = 'my_password';
    $config['smtp_port'] = 465;
    $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
    $config['wrapchars'] = 76;
    $config['mailtype'] = "text";
    $config['charset'] = "utf-8";
    $config['validate'] = FALSE;
    $config['priority'] = 3;
    $config['crlf'] = "\r\n";
    $config['newline'] = "\r\n";
    $config['bcc_batch_mode'] = TRUE;
    $config['bcc_batch_size'] = "200";

    $ci->email->initialize($config);

    $ci->email->from('admin_email');
    $list = array($email);
    $ci->email->to($list);
    $this->email->reply_to('admin_email');
    $ci->email->subject('ACCOUNT ACTIVATION');
    $ci->email->message('Account activation was success');

    $ci->email->send();
```

Then I get an error

```
    Message: fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: unable to connect to ssl://smtp.zoho.com:465 (Connection refused) 
    Filename: libraries/Email.php
```

Comment: try with this $config['smtp_host'] = "smtp.zoho.com";

Comment: @pradeep Still the same result

Comment: What version of CI?  It's likely failing on `smtp_crypo`.   
https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html#email-preferences  It's also possible a combination of smtp_crytpo and @pradeep's suggestion.  Check zoho smtp requirements to see what you need to send it.   I had this issue when using mailgun

Answer (score 0):

SMTP email support depends on the host you're using. For example when creating another solution with Sendgrid I discovered Bluehost does not allow external SMTP connections. In situations like that you may need to use a REST API to bypass the limitations.